# Ferrite bead for use for filtering a microSD card's Vcc

Tags: inductor, sd, microsd, ferrite-bead

I am hoping to use a microSD card in an AVR project and am just trying to find values for all my components.

However, I am not sure what value of ferrite to use here. The few microSD schematics that I've seen with a bead just said "FERRITE" and didn't specify an inductance, or an impedance at a given frequency.

I have an Olimex development board with a full-size SD card using a 470 nH inductor here ([PX128A1](https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Proto/AVR-PX128A1/)).

[image: Schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNDasv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this an appropriate inductor for a microSD card's supply voltage as well?

Edit: the accepted answer is a good general answer, but I also have specific example of another Olimex board using a microSD. The [OLiniXino](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/) board ([schematics](https://raw.github.com/OLIMEX/OLINUXINO/master/HARDWARE/A10-OLinuXino-MICRO/A10-OLINUXINO-MICRO_Rev_B.sch.pdf)) uses a microSD with a 470 nH/1.76 R/250 mA inductor for Vcc filtering. They use the same inductors for SD/MCC and microSD. I suspect this is due to being able to reuse an inventory part, but at least it shows a known-working value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bead is meant to absorb high-frequency noise currents (and dissipate it as heat) to maintain adequate high-frequency separation between shared power rails. 
There is a common type of ferrite beads that are designed to do exactly that. These beads have high impedance over wide high-frequency bands (low-pass filters).

Typical parameters are
- DC resistance -> should be as low as possible
- rated current -> requirements obviously depend on the load
- impedance characteristics curve -> depends on what kind of noise you primarily want to suppress

Look at the parameters of [this ferrite bead](http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/782422601.pdf) for example:

[image: Parameters]

This would actually be a good choice for your design. It has a low DC resistance of 0.8 Ohm (minor losses) and is rated for 200mA. The average microSD shouldn't require more than 100mA (but look at the data sheet to be sure).

[image: impedance curve]

This shows impedance VS frequency. High-frequency noise, especially in the range from about 7MHz-3000MHz, will be absorbed.